# How should I do to identify an error point in assetic:dump of Symfony2?

Tags: javascript, jquery, symfony, yui, assetic

This is an error of assetic:dump in Symfony2.

```
[Assetic\Exception\FilterException]                                                                                                                                                      
  An error occurred while running:                                                                                                                                                         
  '/usr/bin/java' '-jar' '/path/to/java/yuicompressor-2.4.8.jar' '--charset' 'UTF-8' '-o' '/tmp/YUI-OUT-NynbGd' '--type' 'js' '/tmp/YUI-IN-2GZ9rr'  
  Error Output:                                                                                                                                                                            
  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException                                                                                                                   
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)                                                                                                                          
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)                                                                                                        
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)                                                                                                
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)                                                                                                                                     
    at com.yahoo.platform.yui.compressor.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:21)                                                                                                                  
  Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0                                                                                                                        
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:635)                                                                                                                                   
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:411)                                                                                                                                          
    at com.yahoo.platform.yui.compressor.JavaScriptCompressor.getToken(JavaScriptCompressor.java:578)                                                                                       
    at com.yahoo.platform.yui.compressor.JavaScriptCompressor.printSymbolTree(JavaScriptCompressor.java:1094)                                                                               
    at com.yahoo.platform.yui.compressor.JavaScriptCompressor.compress(JavaScriptCompressor.java:556)                                                                                       
    at com.yahoo.platform.yui.compressor.YUICompressor.main(YUICompressor.java:186)                                                                                                         
    ... 5 more
  Input:
```

I think an error is somewhere of a script.

How should I do to identify an error point?

Answer (score 0):

In the most cases the problem is occured by the parameters or paths. I had similar problem with assetic previously, then I managed to solve it using:

- Try to figure it out from the documentation: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/yuicompressor.html
- You can find the exact parameters in vendor/symfony/assetic-bundle/Resources/config/filters

Usually you have to play a bit with the assetic.java.bin or assetic.filter.yui_js.jar

Edit: it looks that you have forgotten to set the yui compressor path: "/path/to/java/yuicompressor-2.4.8.jar"